# What Garmin protocol GPS library for .NET exists

Tags: .net, gps, garmin

I'm developing a GIS application and I had been using devices that output NMEA protocol. There are lots of libraries for NMEA devices, but for Garmin there is only one that I have found, and it isn`t very complete: OpenGPS.NET

I have two questions:

1. How do I use the library with a USB device that does not create a virtual com?
2. Are there other, preferably free, Garmin libraries?

I have also used Franson GPSgate to convert Garmin to NMEA, but there is a problem when the computer goes into sleep mode. When it returns I have to reset the GPS device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**GPS Toolkit.NET**](http://www.scientificcomponent.com/gps_toolkit_net_help/docs/introduction.htm) may suit your needs:

[This link to their sample projects](http://www.scientificcomponent.com/gps_toolkit_net_help/docs/sampleprojects.htm) shows at least one sample project as follows:

> Garmin Test Panel
>
> The Garmin Test Panel project
>   demonstrates much of the functionality
>   available when using GPS ToolKit.NET
>   with a Garmin GPS using the Garmin
>   protocol. This includes access to
>   position, speed, and direction data,
>   as well as as well as the ability to
>   transfer waypoints, routes, and
>   tracks. You can use this project to
>   test communications with the GPS or to
>   jump start your own project.
>
> The Garmin Test Panel Visual Basic.NET
>   sample project can be found in the
>   Examples\VB\Garmin Test Panel folder.
>
> The Garmin Test Panel C# sample
>   project can be found in the
>   Examples\C#\Garmin Test Panel folder.
>
> The Garmin Test Panel C++ sample
>   project can be found in the
>   Examples\C++\Garmin Test Panel folder.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [my project on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opensportsman/)

Testing was done with a garmin forerunner 305. The code should be eay to extend to include the outstanding protocols. The only requirement for the library to work is a that the garmin drivers needs to be installed.